# how do you set the implicit wait time in site-prism?

Tags: site-prism

Left to it's own devices Site-prism does not use implicit waits. On the website it shows that you can allow implicit waits by setting    `use_implicit_waits = true`. The site does not however show how to actually set the implicit wait value and the ruby doc does not show anything that was helpful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set this is to set the value of `Capybara.default_wait_time`

If using cucumber, set it in `env.rb` as `Capybara.default_wait_time = 3` or

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_wait_time = 3
end
```

If using rspec purely, set it in `spec_helper.rb`

The previous answer by clancey from above was only existent for about half of the 2.x revision, and is no longer present in V3 of the API. See https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/blob/master/UPGRADING.md for more information

Answer (score 0):

Using the config in https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/pull/43, this seems to work for me

```
SitePrism.configure do |config|
  config.use_implicit_waits = true
end
```

Comment: Right but this does not specify the duration you want to wait. I am guessing I may need to set it in capybara.